# How to run SQL Server query in AzureMobile with paramterized data

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

My query like this

```
var query = {
    sql: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IN ('@value')",
    parameters: [
        {name: 'values', value: "a,b,c"}
    ]
};
```

I tried array as well but nothing is working. I searched on doc as well but nothing helpful there as well

Comment: You haven't described the problem. No data? Error message (post it)? Screen explodes? At a guess you need to remove the single quotes around `@value`

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Mobile Apps Node.js SDK uses the [mssql Node.js package](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) to connect to Azure SQL Database and query data. It has **not** been supported by a parameterized array in the `query` object yet. See [here](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/313) and [here](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/399).

You could parameterize each value as shown below:

```
var query = {
    sql: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IN (@value1, @value2, @value3)",
    parameters: [
        { name: 'value1', value: 'a'},
        { name: 'value2', value: 'b'},
        { name: 'value3', value: 'c'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please show how to actually run this? And as a bonus, how to execute multiple statements in the same context/transaction?